# Finding the volume by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=\sin(x)$, $y=0$, $x=0$, $x= \pi$ about $y=-1$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, homework

I would like to find the volume of the region obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=\sin(x)$, $y=0$, $x=0$, $x=\pi$ about $y=-1$.

Calc 2 wasn't a strong suit of mine, so this question has taken me over an hour to work on and I haven't made any headway. I can't figure out the coding that would allow me to solve this. I've tried to do it by hand, but gotten to various different answers, so I'm hoping I can find a code that gives an accurate answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you meant to post on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: the question has to be done with Mathematica, so I'm trying to figure out the code. it's not for calc 2, it's for another class where we just solve problems using the mathematica system

Comment: `Integrate[yourFunctionHere, {x,0,Pi}]` or `Integrate[yourFunctionHere, {y,0,1}` depending on the integral you're trying to do.